# How to map function over tf dataset if it's necessary to know the rank and/or shape of the tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to map a function across a tensorflow DatasetV1Adapter, whereby strings are split and then padded to a fixed length.

N.B. I'm stuck doing it this way as opposed to using the new TextVectorization layer for a few different reasons, so have to persist with this unless I go with a more fundamental workaround that leads to losing the efficiencies of tf.Dataset.

```py
# Load raw data and print an example

import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf

imdb_reviews = tfds.load('imdb_reviews')

train_raw = imdb_reviews['train']
test_raw = imdb_reviews['test']

for item in train_raw.take(1):
    print(item['label'].numpy())
    print(item['text'].numpy())

>>0
>>b"This was an absolutely terrible movie. Don't be lured in by Christopher Walken..."

# What I want to be able to do - i.e. split the string, then pad/truncate to length of 500

def format_dataset(input_data):
    split = tf.strings.split(input_data['text'])
    padded = tf.pad(split, [[0, tf.reduce_max(0, 500-split.shape[1])]]) 
    truncated = tf.slice(padded, (padded.shape[1]-500), (500))
    return (truncated, input_data['label'])

train_dataset = train_raw.map(format_dataset)
test_dataset = test_raw.map(format_dataset)
text_dataset = train_raw.map(lambda data: data['text'])

# Output:

StagingError: in converted code:

    <ipython-input-6-ab0bc0f31784>:11 format_dataset  *
        padded = tf.pad(split, [[0, tf.reduce_max(0, 500-split.shape[1])]])
    /sample_code/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/tensor_shape.py:863 __getitem__
        return self._dims[key].value

    IndexError: list index out of range

# Because the graph hasn't allocated a specific shape or rank for the tensors in my map function

print(split.shape)
print(type(split))
>>(None,)
>><class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
```

Is there a way to force it to hold a specific rank/shape in an instance like this where I do actually know in advance exactly what data I will be feeding through?

I tried using len(split) and len(padded) instead of split.shape[1] and padded.shape[1] just to see if I could make it resilient to unknown shapes, but this is the output:

```py
ValueError: in converted code:

    <ipython-input-8-cdf7ac32954b>:14 format_dataset  *
        truncated = tf.slice(padded, (len(padded)-500), (500))
    /sample_code/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/array_ops.py:951 slice
        return gen_array_ops._slice(input_, begin, size, name=name)
    /sample_code/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py:8451 _slice
        "Slice", input=input, begin=begin, size=size, name=name)
    /sample_code/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py:742 _apply_op_helper
        attrs=attr_protos, op_def=op_def)
    /sample_code/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py:595 _create_op_internal
        compute_device)
    /sample_code/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:3322 _create_op_internal
        op_def=op_def)
    /sample_code/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1786 __init__
        control_input_ops)
    /sample_code/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1622 _create_c_op
        raise ValueError(str(e))

    ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 0 for 'Slice' (op: 'Slice') with input shapes: [?], [], [].
```